# Copy / Emulate the entire website - WordPress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, html

I purchased this theme https://themeforest.net/item/seo-business-seo-social-media-marketing-wordpress-theme/17623703 and I want the website to look like exactly as in the live preview(themeforest example)

I installed the wordpress but now it's look like in the picture [http://imgur.com/a/YS1Km](https://imgur.com/a/YS1Km)

I want to look like exactly as live preview from themeforest example

I think I can import that demo content, I don't know, may be exist a plugin ... ?

Thank you very much in  advance !

Comment: you want to install the  theme on an empty wordpress installation ?

Comment: You should definitely contact the customer support. They will help you straight forward...

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you would do is install the theme which you've already done. Next you would follow any prompts to install the recommended plugins that come with the theme.

Once activated, there should be instructions on how to import the demo content. Now this is where you want to be careful. If you already have content on your website then you should skip this step. Otherwise you can follow the steps to import the content and then start replacing the demo content with your own.

You should also make note of the image sizes and dimensions that the theme recommends. This will ensure your website will look like the demo site. Improper image sizes can cause design issues.

You would need to use one or more plugins to install the demo content.

- [WordPress Importer Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/)
- [WordPress Widget Importer Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-importer-exporter/)

There should also be a set of instructions on how to set things up properly.
You may need to adjust your frontpage settings if it's using a static page or blogroll page.

I also recommend using the Regenerate Thumbnails Plugin if you currently have images on your website.

Two locations you will typically work with in properly configuring your website is the Appearance -> Customizer and the Appearance -> Widgets areas.

If the suggestions above aren't helpful or the theme doesn't follow best practices when it comes to documentation, then I recommend contacting the developer directly and asking for some guidance or assistance.

Hopefully this answer helps. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

do next  steps

Step A

1) theme https://themeforest.net/item/seo-business-seo-social-media-marketing-wordpress-theme/17623703 
add opn FTP where you install wordpress 
- you did it

2) when theme installed you need

a) download plugins what theme required and activate them

if you active theme with plugins do "B" step

step B

live preview  possible only whan you have xml file what usual brings with theme, 
 (upload folder)

Step C

Install/Active wordpress import Tools\Import  get file in Step B

Load file, whait few minutes !

Sometimes, need start 2 times - load xml !

After, install theme\plugin and load info.
Check, if there new pages in @Pages@and Posts
Go  Settings Reading  - and check page what you need, because in normal mode work Blog only like here [http://imgur.com/a/YS1Km](https://imgur.com/a/YS1Km)